# Security game between challenger and adversary

Tags: signature, forgery

In Section 2.1 and Section 2.2 of the paper [Strongly Unforgeable Signatures Based on Computational Diffie-Hellman" by Dan Boneh et. al.](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/strongsigs.pdf)", I noticed the paragraphs quoted as

"We define the advantage of an adversary A in attacking the signature scheme as the probability that A wins the above game, **taken over the random bits of the challenger and the adversary**."

"We define the advantage of an adversary A in weakly attacking a signature scheme as the probability that A wins the above game, **taken over the random bits of the challenger and the adversary**."

What exactly is the message being conveyed by the condition "taken over the random bits of the challenger and the adversary"? Is this condition a must-have?

Can anyone offer me an explanation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I found an answer to my question. If I understood correctly, "taken over the random bits of the challenger and the adversary" simply tries to state that the probability of winning a game is calculated based on "the randomness used by Adversary and the challenger".

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE! The probability statement here simply explicitely states the underlying random experiment.